# .NET 8 C#: SslStream "Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received."

Tags: c#, .net, tls1.2, tcpclient, sslstream

I have two .NET 8 C# applications communicating with one another from two separate servers. I am attempting to use `SslStream` secure TCP.  I am getting an error re: the Authentication between the two applications, and I would please like guidance on how to fix this error.

Here is my code that reads a message.

```
string ReadMessage(SslStream sslStream)
{
    // Read the  message sent by the server.
    // The end of the message is signaled using the
    // "<EOF>" marker.
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    StringBuilder messageData = new StringBuilder();
    int bytes = -1;
    do
    {
        bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        // Use Decoder class to convert from bytes to UTF8
        // in case a character spans two buffers.
        Decoder decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
        char[] chars = new char[decoder.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, bytes)];
        decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, bytes, chars, 0);
        messageData.Append(chars);
        // Check for EOF.
        if (messageData.ToString().Contains("<EOF>", StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
        {
            break;
        }
    } while (bytes != 0);

    return messageData.ToString();
}
```

On the line `bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)` I am getting the following error:

> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received.
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.GetFrameSize(ReadOnlySpan1 buffer)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 estimatedSize)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder1.StateMachineBox1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](Memory1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](Memory1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder1.StateMachineBox1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)

I can confirm the following about my connection and certs:

- Protocol: Tls12
- Is authenticated as server: True
- Is encrypted: True
- Can read: True
- Can write: True

Comment: gRPC and SignalR are a thing, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Neither of those protocols is allowed in my corporate environment @Charlieface 

Comment: Hmmm, might end up one of those blogs about "stupid cybersecurity". Instead you are going to reinvent it, badly in many way. Even the small amount of code you posted has big issues: `ToString` on every read, possibly broken UTF8 mutilbyte characters, the way you handle message framing is  going to end up dumping the beginning of the next message, lack of async.

Comment: Wow, that is all valuable feedback! That helps me make a case to my superiors. Thank you!

Comment: did you ever solve the problem? I might have a similar issue with ftp and it started suddenly on processes that were working from years...